# статистика телеграм бота на python

Tags: python, telebot, статистика

Помогите пожалуйста с решением проблемы. Пытаюсь сделать статистику телеграм-бота, счетчик пользователей реализовал, добавив в команду старт следующий код (занесение user_id в текстовый файл):

```
file = open('stat.txt', 'r+')
database_id = file.read()
if str(message.from_user.id) in database_id:
    file.close()
else:
    file.write(datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%d-%m-%Y") + " " + str(message.from_user.id) + "\n")
    file.close()
```

в команду статистики для считывания добавил:

```
def stat(message):
    with open('stat.txt', 'r') as file:
        count_users = len(file.readlines())
```

то есть считаем количество строк, это и есть пользователи бота.
Но вот хочу сделать количество новых пользователей за последние 7 дней, никак не могу сообразить, как это реализовать, хочу сделать так, чтобы из файла выводилось количество строк с датой за последние 7 дней. Пример файла тхт:

[image: пример файла тхт]

Answer (score 0):

Берем первую дату `i`, далее от нее идем. Если следующие даты в диапазоне `i+7`, то берем их в вывод ‍♂️